# Apache - Process not killed after getting Timed-out

Tags: apache-2.2

How to kill a process automatically, it it times out.

I've a configuration which has been set as follow:-

```
#
# Timeout: The number of seconds before receives and sends time out.
#
Timeout 300
```

Upon looking at server-status, I can see a process is still running and is expecting a response from the server(might also have been stuck in between) from over `99633 secs` ,ie over a day(27 hours). Although I've set the conf to 5 minutes, it is still stuck somewhere in between.

How would I kill this process if it takes over 5 minutes?

I'm using Apache2 version in Debian OS. My configyration file is placed in `/etc/apache2/apache.conf`

Comment: Is killing that process is really necessary? its not adviseable to do it. Setting ulimit will limit the RAM available with process.

Answer (score 1):

If interested in ulimit ,you can check man pages for it.

http://linux.die.net/man/3/ulimit

OR

check this link i found it in another sister site of stackexchange

https://askubuntu.com/questions/54747/automatically-kill-a-process-if-it-exceeds-a-given-amount-of-ram

Comment: I'll check that out. But what does timeout means in the conf file? It should automatically kill the process. Shouldnt it.

Comment: Timeout defines, in seconds, the amount of time that the server waits for receipts and transmissions during communications. Timeout is set to 300 seconds by default, which is appropriate for most situations.If you were running PHP as CGI, and not trickling back some input in that loop, Apache's CGI module would give up based on the Timeout. But since you run mod_php, nobody but PHP is watching the clock.